# From Rails to Mongodb connection over ssl not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I am able to connect mongodb from mongo shell over ssl(working):
mongo --ssl --sslCAFile ca.crt --sslPEMKeyFile client.pem mongodb://xxxx:xxxx@xxxxx:27017/test_db?authSource=admin

From rails I am not able to connect my mongoid config file follows :

```
development:
  clients:
    default:
      #database: mastt_development
      uri: mongodb://xxxx:xxxx@xxxxx:27017/test_db?authSource=admin
#      hosts:
#        - localhost:27017
  options:
    max_pool_size: 3
    wait_queue_timeout: 300
    ssl: true
    ssl_cert: /home/ubuntu/client.pem
    ssl_verify: true
    ssl_ca_cert: /home/ubuntu/ca.crt
 options:
    raise_not_found_error: false

rails c
2.6.2 :001 > User.count
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):1
Mongo::Error::NoServerAvailable (No primary server is available in cluster: #<Cluster topology=Unknown[prod-mongo-v2:27017] servers=[#<Server address=prod-mongo-v2:27017 UNKNOWN>]> with timeout=30, LT=0.015)
2.6.2 :002 > exit
```

MongDB server Log :

```
2020-06-12T06:22:05.955+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn680] end connection xx.xx.xx.xx:55240 (0 connections now open)
2020-06-12T06:22:16.549+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from xx.xx.xx.xx:55241 #681 (1 connection now open)
2020-06-12T06:22:16.559+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn681] Error receiving request from client: SSLHandshakeFailed: The server is configured to only allow SSL connections. Ending connection from 157.45.197.173:55241 (connection id: 681)
```

Please help to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1):

You are setting those options as Mongoid options but they need to be set as driver options. See [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-configuration/#configuration-options) for an example.

Briefly, move the first  `options` to be on the same level as `uri` in your configuration.

You also have `options` twice on top level seemingly.

Comment: Thank you very much. The first options moving worked fine. The second option is at the correct position